# Mathematical integrity of NSDecimalNumber

Tags: ios, nsdecimalnumber

I'm using numbers divided by 10^30

I may be adding values like 1000000000000000 and 5000000000000000 stored in `NSDecimalNumber`s.

My concern is that I think I've seen a few times, when adding or subtracting these values, incorrect math being done.

Is that a possibility or are `NSDecimalNumbers` pretty sound in terms of the integrity of their math.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: I'm trying to recreate now and I will

Comment: @ZackShapiro You should use Swift native types such as `Decimal`

Comment: What benefits does it have over NSDecimalNumber other than being a native swift type?

Comment: Benefits include (a) value vs reference semantics; (b) elimination of `NS` syntactic noise; (c) built-in `+`, `-`, etc., operators resulting in more natural and intuitive code. And, as [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/working_with_foundation_types), “When importing the Foundation framework, the Swift overlay provides value types for many bridged reference types. ... Prefer Swift value types to bridged Objective-C reference types”.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your question, the math offered by `Decimal`/`NSDecimalNumber` is sound, and the problem probably rests in either:

1. The calculations might exceed the capacity of these decimal formats (as outlined by rob mayoff). For example, this works because we're within the 38 digit mantissa:

   ```
   let x = Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: 60, significand: 1)
   let y = Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: 30, significand: 1)
   let z = x + y
   ```

   > 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,001,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

   But this will not:

   ```
   let x = Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: 60, significand: 1)
   let y = Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: 10, significand: 1)
   let z = x + y
   ```

   > 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
2. Or, it could just be how you are instantiating these decimal values, e.g. supplying a floating point number rather than using the `Decimal(sign:exponent:significand:)` or `NSDecimalNumber(mantissa:exponent:isNegative:)` initializers:

   For example, this works fine:

   ```
   let formatter = NumberFormatter()
   formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

   let x = Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: 30, significand: 1)
   print(formatter.string(for: x)!)
   ```

   That results in:

   > 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

   But these won't, because you're supplying a floating point number which suffers lower limits in precision:

   ```
   let y = Decimal(1.0e30)
   print(formatter.string(for: y)!)

   let z = Decimal(1_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000.0)
   print(formatter.string(for: z)!)
   ```

   These both result in:

   > 1,000,000,000,000,000,409,600,000,000,000

For more information on floating-point arithmetic (and why certainly decimal numbers cannot be perfectly captured in floating-point types), see [floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic).

---

In [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48329601/1271826), you ask why the following:

```
let foo = NSDecimalNumber(value: 334.99999).multiplying(byPowerOf10: 30)
```

produced:

> 334999990000000051200000000000000

This is the same underlying issue that I outlined above in point 2. Floating point numbers cannot accurately represent certain decimal values.

Note, your question is the same as the following `Decimal` rendition:

```
let adjustment = Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: 30, significand: 1)
let foo = Decimal(334.99999) * adjustment
```

This also produces:

> 334999990000000051200000000000000

But you will get the desired result if you supply either a string or a exponent and mantissa/significant, because these will be accurately represented as a `Decimal`/`NSDecimalNumber`:

```
let bar = Decimal(string: "334.99999")! * adjustment
let baz = Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: -5, significand: 33499999) * adjustment
```

Those both produce:

> 334999990000000000000000000000000

Bottom line, do not supply floating point numbers to `Decimal` or `NSDecimalNumber`. Use string representations or use the exponent and mantissa/significand representation and you will not see these strange deviations introduced when using floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using numbers divided by 1^30

Good news, then, because 1^30 = 1. Perhaps you meant 10^30?

Anyway, according to the [`NSDecimalNumber` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber):

> An instance can represent any number that can be expressed as mantissa x 10^exponent where mantissa is a decimal integer up to 38 digits long, and exponent is an integer from –128 through 127.